# Alloy modeling language - how to write filters?

Tags: logic, relational, alloy, formal-verification

How can I write a filter function in Alloy?

For example If I have:

```
sig Student {
    enrollments: set Enrollment
}

sig Course {}

abstract sig Status {}

one sig Complete, Incomplete extends Status {}

sig Enrollment {
    student: Student,
    course: Course,
    status: Status
}
```

How can I, for a given student, check if he completed a given course?

I suppose I'd have to write a function that for a student `s` returns its completed courses:

```
fun completed[s: Student]: set Course { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing such a function is indeed a possibility. I think that, to formalize a property successfully, you should first state your query in simple terms, e.g.: you want to return the set of courses followed by `s` that are completed. With that said, the formalization is fairly easy with a **comprehension set**. Later, you may try to see whether you can achieve the same result with other Alloy constructs.

Comment: set comprehension here is an overkill, simple relational logic is enough and less complex to solve :) (-> faster instance generation)

Comment: This is why I wrote: "Later, you may try to see whether you can achieve the same result with other Alloy constructs".

Answer (score 0):

The term filter is somehow misleading. If you want to write a function that returns the set of completed course to which a student s is enrolled then you are on the right track.

You just need to feel those dots by the right expression. An intersection using the & operator will definitely do the trick to only consider completed enrollements.

Note that if you are only interested in answering the yes/no question: Did the student complete a given course, then declaring a predicate taking the given course as parameter would be a more appropriate solution.